# Purview deleting a classification

Tags: classification, azure-purview

I have created a custom classification in Purview which is looking for a specific column name from a SQL Server source.

The scan does pick up the classification and assign it to the column accordingly, however when i delete the classification rule, I select "Delete this rule and delete all applied classifications", the column that was detected still has the classification assigned to it, and I am unable to delete the custom classification as it is still referenced by the column.

The workaround is to manually remove it from the column first which is not ideal, especially if it is assigned to multiple columns.

In purview, create custom classification to detect specific column text.

Perform scan, new classification is applied to column.

Delete custom classification rules and select "Delete this rule and delete all applied classifications"

Try and delete custom classification - unable to as it is still referenced by the column that was detected by the scan.

Comment: You stated that one can manually remove a classification. Can you please explain how? I have posted the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75478611/1232087)