# How to delete a classification in Purview

Tags: azure, azure-purview

**Question**: How do you manually remove a `classification` from an `asset`?

This [article from Purview team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/catalog-asset-details) gives many details on editing an asset's values, but I don't see how to manually remove a `classification` from an asset.

Comment: Check if this help in this ask [Link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/purview/manually-apply-classifications.md)

Answer (score 0):

Open an object in a Catalog --> Edit --> Schema, you'll see a list of columns and corresponding classifications. Remove it from there.